# Is there any mysql/Oracle function to give incremental no. to one column on the basis of another columns of similar values?

Tags: mysql, oracle, function, count

I am interested to know that **Is there any mysql/Oracle function to give incremental no. to one column on the basis of another columns of similar  values?**

Like in my below code, I have order_primary column which contains order no. so based on that we can identify how many products belongs to particular order. Also count is for storing those values like 1,2,3 etc.
But I am facing problem that count value is just going incrementaing...

My code-:

```
$query_product = "SELECT name, id,qty_ordered,price,row_total,base_subtotal, 
base_shipping_amount,base_grand_total,order_primary,message
FROM  sales_order WHERE `prod_Flag`=0 ";

$result_query_product = mysql_query($query_product);
        $count = 0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_query_product))
        {
            $count++;
            $name = ($row["name"]);
            $message1 = ($row["message"]);
                 $result_str_product .= "('". mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "',". "'" . $row["sku"] . "'," . "'" . $row["qty_ordered"] . "',". "'" . $row["price"] . "'," . "'" . $row["row_total"] . "'," . "'" . $row["base_subtotal"]. "'," . "'" . $row["base_shipping_amount"] . "'," . "'" . $row["base_grand_total"] ."',". $row["order_primary"].",". $count.",". "'".mysql_real_escape_string($message1)."'".", NOW()),";      
        }


        $query_prod_insert = "INSERT into sales_product(name, sku, qty_ordered, price, row_total, base_subtotal,    base_shipping_amount,base_grand_total,prod_foreign,count,message,product_creation_date) VALUES ".$result_str_product;
    $final_query = substr_replace($query_prod_insert,";",-1);
    $result_query_product_outbound = mysql_query($final_query);
```

So My o/p is-:

```
('shirt','st','2.0000','75','150','150','20','170',29,1,NOW()),
    ('tie'  ,'te','2.0000','50','100','100','10','110',29,2,NOW()),
    ('tie'  ,'te','2.0000','50','100','100','10','110',29,3,NOW()),                   
('socks','sk','5.0000','20','100','100','05','105',30,4,NOW()); 
    ('jackt','jt','3.0000','40','120','120','15','135',30,5,NOW());
```

But I want o/p like this-:

```
 ('shirt','st','2.0000','75','150','150','20','170',29,**1**,NOW()),
    ('tie'  ,'te','2.0000','50','100','100','10','110',29,**2**,NOW()),
    ('tie'  ,'te','2.0000','50','100','100','10','110',29,**3**,NOW()),

('socks','sk','5.0000','20','100','100','05','105',30,**1**,NOW()); 
    ('jackt','jt','3.0000','40','120','120','15','135',30,**2**,NOW());
```

**So Is there any mysql/Oracle function to give incremental no. to one column on the basis of another columns of similar  values i.e. in my case, for same order no. value say 29, count values should be 1,2,3 & for same order no. 30, count value should be 1,2...**

So is there any function or how to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle this is pretty easy:

```
SELECT order_no, 
       row_number() over (partition by order_no order by order_primary) as rn
FROM sales_product
```

Note: I'm guessing the column names as they are somewhere hidden in the PHP(?) code. Please adjust them according to your table structure. For future posts you should also include the corresponding CREATE TABLE statement in your question.

Comment: @Prat: MySQL does not support this feature.